# ef core query result navigation collection contains deleted entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

By reading this post [relationship-changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes). In many-to-many relationships, I consider when removing join entities `PostTags` from `post.PostTags` the removed entity will also disapper from `tag.PostTags`

If query tags before `ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` it performs as expected.

However in `UnitTest1.cs` call `ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` before query tags, the `tag{id=2}`'s navigation property `PostTags` still has `{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}` which state is deleted.

It dosen't disapper although I call `ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` again

how to make DetectChanges has consistent result, no matter what order of invocation.

Entities

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Web.Tests
{ 
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public IList<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>(); // Collection navigation
    }

    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public IList<PostTag> PostTags { get; } = new List<PostTag>(); // Collection navigation
    }

    public class PostTag
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; } // First part of composite PK; FK to Post
        public int TagId { get; set; } // Second part of composite PK; FK to Tag

        public Post Post { get; set; } // Reference navigation
        public Tag Tag { get; set; } // Reference navigation
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Web.Tests
{
    public class BlogContext : DbContext
    {
        public BlogContext(DbContextOptions<BlogContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
                .HasData(
                    new Post { Id = 1, Title = "How to use vs?", Content = "blababa" }
                );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>()
                .HasData(
                    new Tag { Id = 1, Text = ".NET" },
                    new Tag { Id = 2, Text = "C#" }

                );
            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
                .HasKey(x => new { x.PostId, x.TagId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Post)
                .WithMany(x => x.PostTags);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Tag)
                .WithMany(x => x.PostTags);

            modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
                .HasData(
                    new PostTag { PostId = 1, TagId = 1 },
                    new PostTag { PostId = 1, TagId = 2 }
                );

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

UnitTest1.cs

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var ctx = CreateContext();
            var post = ctx.Posts.Include(x => x.PostTags).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
            if (post != null)
            {
                post.PostTags.RemoveAt(1);
            }

            
            ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

            var tag = ctx.Tags.Include(x => x.PostTags).ToList();
            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

            ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);


            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

```
 Post {Id: 1} Unchanged
   Id: 1 PK
   Content: 'blababa'
   Title: 'How to use vs?'
   PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
 PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 1} Unchanged
   PostId: 1 PK FK
   TagId: 1 PK FK
   Post: {Id: 1}
   Tag: <null>
 PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 2} Deleted
   PostId: 1 PK FK
   TagId: 2 PK FK
   Post: <null>
   Tag: <null>
```

```
 Post {Id: 1} Unchanged
   Id: 1 PK
   Content: 'blababa'
   Title: 'How to use vs?'
   PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
 PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 1} Unchanged
   PostId: 1 PK FK
   TagId: 1 PK FK
   Post: {Id: 1}
   Tag: {Id: 1}
 PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 2} Deleted
   PostId: 1 PK FK
   TagId: 2 PK FK
   Post: <null>
   Tag: {Id: 2}
 Tag {Id: 1} Unchanged
   Id: 1 PK
   Text: '.NET'
   PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
 Tag {Id: 2} Unchanged
   Id: 2 PK
   Text: 'C#'
   PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}]
```

```
Post {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Content: 'blababa'
  Title: 'How to use vs?'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 1} Unchanged
  PostId: 1 PK FK
  TagId: 1 PK FK
  Post: {Id: 1}
  Tag: {Id: 1}
PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 2} Deleted
  PostId: 1 PK FK
  TagId: 2 PK FK
  Post: <null>
  Tag: {Id: 2}
Tag {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Text: '.NET'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
Tag {Id: 2} Unchanged
  Id: 2 PK
  Text: 'C#'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}]
```

**Update**

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var ctx = CreateContext();
            var post = ctx.Posts.Include(x => x.PostTags).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1);
            if (post != null)
            {
                post.PostTags.RemoveAt(1);
            }

            //ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            //Debug.WriteLine(ctx.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

            var tag = ctx.Tags.Include(x => x.PostTags).ToList();
            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);

            ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
            Debug.WriteLine(ctx.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);


            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

```
Post {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Content: 'blababa'
  Title: 'How to use vs?'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 1} Unchanged
  PostId: 1 PK FK
  TagId: 1 PK FK
  Post: {Id: 1}
  Tag: {Id: 1}
PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 2} Unchanged
  PostId: 1 PK FK
  TagId: 2 PK FK
  Post: {Id: 1}
  Tag: {Id: 2}
Tag {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Text: '.NET'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
Tag {Id: 2} Unchanged
  Id: 2 PK
  Text: 'C#'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}]
```

```
 Post {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Content: 'blababa'
  Title: 'How to use vs?'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 1} Unchanged
  PostId: 1 PK FK
  TagId: 1 PK FK
  Post: {Id: 1}
  Tag: {Id: 1}
PostTag {PostId: 1, TagId: 2} Deleted
  PostId: 1 PK FK
  TagId: 2 PK FK
  Post: <null>
  Tag: {Id: 2}
Tag {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Text: '.NET'
  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 1}]
Tag {Id: 2} Unchanged
  Id: 2 PK
  Text: 'C#'
  PostTags: []    //this is the point.
```

Comment: What is the question? That article says that relations are fixed up automatically. `DetectChanges` is only needed when you want to view some of those changes using a debug view. `SaveChanges` itself will check for changes before generating the SQL commands that save the changes

Comment: this is a demo. In my project I need use the Tag.PostTags to calculate for example Tag.total before saveChanges. If Tag.PostTags not fixup. It will get the wrong value.

Comment: If I remove  PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}] from post. The Tag {Id: 2} should not have PostTags: [{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}]  event I invoke a new query. It  should  be consistent with local data, not database.

Comment: my question is if I query the Tags to local first, then call ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() it performs as expected. why call ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() repeatedly not working.

Comment: Why? You haven't stored the changes. What you posted is what one would expect - there's a pending `Deleted` for an object instance with keys `{PostId: 1, TagId: 2}` and another, completely different object instance with the same keys but no changes. When you call `SaveChanges` the `Deleted` change will be used to generate a `DELETE`

Comment: `why call ctx.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() repeatedly not working.` it's working perfectly. Either you assume it does something it's not meant to do or you're checking it the wrong way. You aren't checking for any tag counts in the *modified* objects to begin with. Your `post*s*` contains different object instances from your `tag*s*` list. Your code isn't checking the contents of either. It's checking changes that are just as expected

Comment: see the update:)

Comment: Can you write `ChangeTracker.Entity(deletedTag).State`, save changes and then do the whole writeline, and see if it is indeed deleted at both ends?

Comment: I need deleted at both ends before saveChanges(); @AMunim

Comment: yes, after getting getting the post set `ChangeTracker.Entity(posttag).State = State.Deleted` now detect changes and writeline to see if it succeeded

Comment: if I only set `ChangeTracker.Entity(posttag).State = State.Deleted` both ends has the posttag.

Comment: Now you have "I need deleted at both ends before saveChanges();", simply `SaveChanges()` and both of them will be deleted